# How to find and replace in a text editor?

Tags: regex, replace, textwrangler

I am very new to text editing, so I'm sorry if this question is unclear, let me know if there's anything I can specify to make my question more understandable.

My file has 27 tab-separated columns and thousands of rows.  I want to replace  tabs with an underscore (basically merging the first 3 columns together), but only after my first two columns.  How do I do this?

Here's what I currently have for my find:

> ([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([
>   ^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^
>   \t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\r

and then here's my replace:

> \1_\2_\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t\7\t\8\t\9\t\10\t\11\t\12\t\13\t\14\t\15\t\16\t\17\t\18\t\19\t\20\t\21\t\22\t\23\t\24\t\25\t\26\t\27\r

Also, any references to a good regex guide would be welcomed!

Below are representative data.  Each number is separated by a tab in my editor, not by a space.

chr1    28404   29751   25  14  57  42  44  44  56  34  16  24  18  24  24  23  24  163 57  30  28  31  36  23  28  17

chr1    235561  236222  5   13  4   24  4   8   7   6   5   14  20  7   10  3   6   11  9   9   16  8   16  6   11  9

chr1    540455  541272  20  11  6   7   5   7   12  24  7   9   9   6   22  3   10  32  18  22  11  13  10  27  9   10

chr1    713112  715467  96  105 332 159 131 277 225 199 61  164 128 116 156 107 143 687 204 186 97  125 174 193 213 118

chr1    761657  764380  106 153 334 182 161 326 215 343 85  174 160 135 176 151 141 724 308 223 120 141 200 198 247 151

Comment: Could you supply some test data as well?

Comment: Made the change to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Find :

```
(.+?)\t(.+?)\t(.+?)\n
```

Replace with

```
\1_\2_\3\n
```

have a look at [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL3aA4/2)

Moreover you'll have to disable ". matches New Line" in your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have something like

[image]

Running this search and replace below, you will get:

[image]

Regex:

```
^(\s*(?:[^\t]+\t){2})([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t
```

Replacement: `$1$2_$3_`

If you can have empty columns, replace the `+` quantifier to `*`:

```
^(\s*(?:[^\t]*\t){2})([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t
```